# jQuery post not working whereas get works with same structure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've got an ajax call to the following php method:

```
public function test(){
        die(json_encode(['test' => 'test1']));
    }
```

My ajax call works when set as GET but not as POST. The GET call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    success: function(msg) {
        log(msg);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Which successfully returns the JSON element. But when I set it as POST:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    success: function(msg) {
        log(msg);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Returns nothing. If I removed the dataType it will return the whole webpage where it's being triggered from.

I do need to make the request as POST since I'll be sending a large amount of data.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling test()?

Comment: It's part of the url parameter, which I don't think is the issue since it's working with GET

Comment: No.. how are you executing the function test()? And it could be an issue if you are testing for something that is a GET vs POST, and executing test() based on that decision

Comment: I'm sorry, not following. test() belongs to the Ajax.php file, is not being used by anything other than the ajax call. The url in my ajax is something like: myDomain/Ajax/test

Comment: Are you using some php framework that automatically calls a function based on url path?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Codeigniter. It does automatically calls the method based on the url

Comment: show your route config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have CSRF protection enabled?

Comment: It was an issue with CSRF as you pointed out! I set it to FALSE (in the meantime) and it worked. I'll fix it later, at least I'm getting the data back for now. Thanks

Comment: You're welcolme....The problem is with CSRF regeneration...If the token gets regenerated every time than your ajax won't work.I fixed it by setting csrf_regenerate to FALSE.